# What is the default data source name to be passed to get the dec interaction?

Tags: sitefinity

I am creating a Dotnet application to pull out the customer data from the Sitefinity Digital Experience Cloud.

But when I am calling the Interaction API

https://api.dec.sitefinity.com/collect/v2/data-centers/{App KEY}/datasources/{datasourcesname}/interactions

When I had tried passing **Website** as the key it gives 1 as the response instead of the interactions data.

[response data for the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHFwv.png)

What will be the default **dataSourceName** need to be passed with the Sitefinity Digital Experience Cloud API to get the interaction details?

Page tracking code :

`return DataIntelligenceSubmitScript.load({"apiServerUrl":"https://api.dec.sitefinity.com","apiKey":"88cf13bb-3424-12f4-6fc1-19360fexxxxx","applicationName":"Website","trackingCookieDomain":"","keepDecTrackingCookieOnTrackingConsentRejection":false});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use one of the data sources configured under your data center.

Login into the DEC account -> Administration -> Click on the data center you want to use -> Data integration.

Articles that might help with the setup -

1. https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/dec/plug-data-from-data-sources
2. https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/how-to-configure-dec-in-sitefinity-cms